# Finding a javascript element by id

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to download a csv file from a website using selenium, but I am failing in the last step.

I fail at selecting the format of the file and then to click on export. Does someone as any idea on how to do it? There's a free registration process to be able to connect to the website, you would have to register with your email address to try. I have attached a picture and circled in red the part I struggle to automate [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j93wH.jpg). Below is the working code up until before the last step i would like to complete.

Thank you very much for your help!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.sem-o.com/MarketData/pages /default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMarketData%2fPages%2fDynamicReports.aspx")


#log-in
##############
elem =  driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$FBALoginId$username")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("EMAIL")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FBALoginId_password")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("PASSWORD")
#elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

elem =       driver.find_element_by_id(r"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_FBALoginId_btnLogin")
elem.click()
##############




#retrieve files of interest
##############
elem =   Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_g_f5e6fa98_faa2_4210_85e9_780934d96ab8_cmbReportGroup"))
elem.select_by_visible_text('Forecast Data')

elem = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_g_f5e6fa98_faa2_4210_85e9_780934d96ab8_cmbSelectReport"))
elem.select_by_visible_text("Four Day Load Forecast")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id(r"ctl00_ctl00_g_9ab92c0a_eb10_4b6c_ad1b_7277cbdab462_btnGenerateLocalReport")
elem.click()

elem =   driver.find_element_by_id(r"ctl00_ctl00_g_9ab92c0a_eb10_4b6c_ad1b_7277cbdab462_prm_GetFromDate_prm_GetFromDateDate")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("01/01/2017")

elem =     driver.find_element_by_id(r"ctl00_ctl00_g_9ab92c0a_eb10_4b6c_ad1b_7277cbdab462_prm_GetToDate_prm_GetToDateDate")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("15/01/2017")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id(r"ctl00_ctl00_g_9ab92c0a_eb10_4b6c_ad1b_7277cbdab46  2_btnGenerateLocalReport")
elem.click()
```

Comment: @csmckelvey it should be fine now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting?
Which step is it failing at, is it the actual clicking on export? If this is the case, check the way you are identifying the element in the Google dev console. Go to F12 dev tools, then in the console type:

```
$$('#ctl00_ctl00_g_9ab92c0a_eb10_4b6c_ad1b_7277cbdab46.2_btnGenerateLocalReport')
```

This will show all elements with that selected id. If it's an empty array, then the selector is invalid.

You may have to experiment with the id selector as that space looks a bit odd. More information is needed on the error you are getting and why it's failing to provide a better answer.

Comment: There's nothing failing in the code I provided. I just miss the two last steps i circled in red in the picture that I do not know how to do. The code provided are the steps to do before the two last steps i dont know how to do.

Comment: You need to add logging after each action to see what is happening. How do you know it's both steps that's failing as opposed to only the last one, for example?

Comment: because i have done screenshots with my code to print what the code was doing. I just cannot get my code to select the export format and downloading the file once the format selected. This part is not implemented in the code provided, I have tried different things but everything failed because i cannot get the element by id. I suppose it is because its a javascript thing

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested and seeing if the element is valid by looking at the developer console. You said it didn't fail and that it didn't run. Is there anything in the console.log to provide clues as to why it's not occuring/failing?